# How to write a query for Facebook insights in Rails with Koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, koala, koala-gem

I tried without success to write some query in Rails with Koala gem to get data form Facebook Insights for pages.

Can someone help me to write query for URL like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/[Page-ID]/insights/page_fans

I tried:

```
 @graph.get_object("[Page-ID]/insights/page_fans")
```

Answer (score 1):

With this you get page_impressions. You can see a list of complete parameters for metric here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights

`page_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_key)
impressions = page_graph.get_connections('me', 'insights', metric: 'page_impressions', period: 'now')`